# Image of a normal subgroup under a homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> I want to find an example of a group homomorphism $f:G\to H$ such that $A$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, but $f(A)$ is not so in $H$.

Definitely the groups must be noncommutative and the function should not be onto. Please help me.

Comment: Take any nonnormal subgroup $K\subset H$ then let $G=A=K$, and $f$ inclusion.

Answer (score 7):

For instance, you could take any non-normal subgroup $N$ of a group $G$, and let $f$ be the inclusion of $N$ into $G$. Obviously $N$ is normal in $N$, but it isn't normal in $G$...

Can you find an example where $N$ is commutative?

Comment: Let us consider $S_3$ and its subgroup $N=\lbrace e, (1 2)\rbrace$. Then $N$ is abelian but not normal in $S_3$.

Comment: @SucharitaDeb: That's right! :)